# Plone 4.2 - Diazo - rules.xml

Tags: themes, plone, diazo

I'm trying to create theme with diazo on plone 4.2.

#### error message :

*"IOError: Error reading file '/++theme++optilux.theme/**rules.xml**': failed to load external entity "/++theme++optilux.theme/rules.xml""*

#### configuration file buildout.cfg contains :

```
extends =
http://good-py.appspot.com/release/plone.app.theming/1.0b8?plone=4.1
```

#### configuration file configure.zcml contains :

```
<!-- Register the /++theme++optilux.theme/ static resource directory -->
<plone:static
   directory="resources"
   type="theme"
   />
```

#### Directory :

```
--> pwd
/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/src/optilux.theme/optilux/theme
--> ls -l
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1113 aoÃ»  9 16:09 configure.zcml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  119 jui 10 21:40 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 jui 10 21:40 profiles
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 aoÃ»  9 14:57 resources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1383 jui 10 21:40 tests.py
```

#### resources directory : ls -l

```
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5373 jui 11 21:48 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 jui 12 21:49 overrides
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3322 jui 12 21:44 rules.xml
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 jui 11 21:52 stylesheets
```

I hope put all informations needed.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two things to try:

1) **Confirm you're on Plone 4.2** - `plone.app.theming` is part of Plone 4.2, so you don't need to reference `http://good-py.appspot.com` in the buildout. The `buildout.cfg` file should start:

```
[buildout]
extends =
    http://dist.plone.org/release/4.2/versions.cfg
```

2) **Check file/directory permissions and ownership** - It looks like you have installed Plone as root using the Unified Installer. In that case I would expect the [files to be owned by the `plone` user](https://github.com/plone/Installers-UnifiedInstaller/blob/master/README.txt#L382-387). Make sure that the permissions and owners of your files match those of files created by the installer (e.g. what's in `buildout-cache`).